# TurfJS Snap to the second closest

Tags: routes, geospatial, haskell-snap-framework, turfjs

I'm using the TurfJS library in one of my projects to determine the distance to the destination using a defined route as my base, but because of GPS drift, I have a situation where the point snaps to the "other"side of the road/route.

Is there a way to get the second closest line element back, which in theory should be the line going back to the destination?

Any suggestions would be great...!

PS - the image is a representation where the roue is actually coming back on the same road.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, an observation: the second line segment might be on the same "wrong" part of the line as the first one.

What I would use is `lineSlice` function. Once you know vehicle passed particular point, slice the line and get the remaining part. Then find the closest point using this remaining part only.

Comment: Thanks @michael-entin for your insight and suggestion. You are quite right, the point may also snap to the "other" side while on route, then it might look like the vehicle has a shorter distance to go, while it actually it still has a way to go... Bit of an anomaly here.

Comment: BTW, I guess you can similarly estimate maximum distance travelled, and slice the end of the path as well, to reduce false matches further

Comment: Using Slice is a nice way as you can then just use the length of the lines, but the gps drift will still play a role, as if it snaps to the incorrect side, it will throw out the calculation (the image is a bit obscure - imagine if the actually returns on the same path)...

Comment: I used nearestPointOnLine function to give me the length

`var pt = turf.point([ptLongitudeX, ptLatitudeY]);
    var RouteLenth = turf.length(routeData, {units:'kilometers'});
    var ptSnapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(routeData, pt, {units:'kilometers'});

    var ptDistFromStart;
    turf.propEach(ptSnapped, function (currentProperties, featureIndex) {
        ptDistToLine = currentProperties['dist'] * 1000; //to get meters
        ptDistFromStart = currentProperties['location'];  //kilometers
    });
    var ptDistToFinish = RouteLenth - ptDistFromStart;  //kilometers`